# Comparing same two measurements in two groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I am trying to compare two related measurements in two different groups to see if it is increased in one group vs the other, as follows:

1. Measurement 1 in males with a characteristic vs measurement 1 in males without a characteristic
2. Measurement 2 in males with a characteristic vs measurement 2 in males without a characteristic
3. Same as 1 and 2 but in females

Should I use multiple t tests with a correction such as Bonferroni or an unadjusted or sex-adjusted ANOVA and why?

Comment: Why not use regression techniques with, for instance, interactions?